# Simple way to preload images for html canvas (video game application)?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've done some research and found examples using promises, but I'm trying to copy a specific example I found on the internet that loads its images as seen below.
Example code: https://github.com/pinglu85/fcc-secure-real-time-multiplayer-game (see /public/game.mjs and player.mjs if interested)

```
const loadImage = (src) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  return img;
};
const avatar = loadImage('sourceurl.png');
```

They then directly implement within an animation frame render() function with: `context.drawImage(avatar, x, y, width, height);`

I tried implementing this and it failed to render the image(s). Is there something I'm missing? I simply need to get the loaded image in variable I can call in the draw function.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to wait or the load event on the image before trying to draw it in a canvas.

Comment: I don't know what you mean -- wait for the load event? What does this look like?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I finally got something to work:

```
const Images = {}

function loadImages(arr) {
  arr.forEach((elem, i) => {
    let img = new Image();
    Images[elem.name] = img;
    img.onload = () => {
      
    };
    img.src = elem.url;
  })
}
```

You load an array of objects like `[{name: tiger, url: /path/to/file.png}]`